# Running Dijkstra algorithm in parallel using Pthreads in C

Tags: c, pthreads, dijkstra

Hi im attempting to run a sequential version of Dijkstra's Algorithm in parallel using Pthreads. I have successfully made it work using OMP and now im attempting on Pthreads. I have the following code i have written `// THIS LINE` where i believe im encountering problems.

```
/* Create a stuct to hold data for each thread */
struct ThreadData {
    long start, stop;
    graph G;
};

/* This function gets called from the main */
void testScheduler(int nThreads, graph* G)
{
    resetGraph(G); // Make a fresh graph

    struct ThreadData data[nThreads]; // Create stucts to hold each thread information
    pthread_t threads [nThreads]; // Create threads
    int tasksPerThread = ((G->N)+nThreads-1)/nThreads; // Divide up tasks

    /* Do the loop in NUMTHREADS pieces */
    for (int i=0; i<nThreads; i++) {
        data[i].start=i*tasksPerThread;
        data[i].stop=(i+1)*tasksPerThread;
        data[i].G = *G;
    }
    /* The last thread must not go past the size of the graph */
    data[nThreads-1].stop = (G->N);


    /* Launch Threads */
    for (int i=0; i<nThreads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, dijkstra, &data[i]);
    }
    /* Wait for Threads to Finish */
    for (int i=0; i<nThreads; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }


}

void dijkstra(struct ThreadData* td)
{
    long i,j;
    struct ThreadData* data=(struct ThreadData*) td; // This threads data
    long start = data->start; // Starting Point
    long stop = data->stop; // Ending Point
    graph* G = &data->G; // The graph
    long aN; //actualNode

    G->D[start] = 0; // THIS LINE 
    aN = start;     // THIS LINE 


    for(i = start; i < stop; i++)
    {
        G->visited[aN] = VISITED;

        //Find all nodes connected to aN
        for(j=start;j<stop;j++){
            if( (G->node[aN][j] != NO_CONN) ){
                if( (G->D[aN] + G->node[aN][j]) < G->D[j] ){
                    G->D[j] = (G->D[aN] + G->node[aN][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        aN = getNextNode(G);
    }

}
```

Currently i understand im making a new version of `Graph G` for each thread, i have done this so i do not need to use any mutex locks. However this creates the problem because im unable to access the current `aN` or `G->D` variable im up to.

Questions:

If i use a global `Graph G` (with mutex locks) does that mean each thread has to run in the correct order so i can grab the variables from the last thread and continue? If so is there any point in running in parallel if im just waiting for each previous thread to finish?

If i use mutex locks, do i need to lock when reading from a variable or only when writing?

Is there a way to do it similar to the current way i have done?

I am new to pthreads sorry if i have asked any dumb questions.

Comment: when calling library functions, like `pthread_create()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `pthread_t threads [nThreads]; // Create threads`  This is NOT creating threads.  Rather, it is an array that will (eventually) contain the thread IDs

Comment: regarding this function signature: `void dijkstra(struct ThreadData* td)`  this is NOT a valid pthread function signature.  The proper signature is: `void * dijkstra( void * arg )`

Comment: the lines marked with: `THIS LINE` are referencing a data structure `Graph` however, that data structure is not defined anywhere in the posted code

Comment: the macro `VISITED` and macro `NO_CONN` are not defined anywhere in the posted code

Comment: the function: `getNextNode()` is not defined anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your code includes?  Please post a [mcve] so we can assist you